# Prove $\frac{d}{dx}[\csc^{[-1]}{x} = \frac{-1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, derivatives, proof-verification

Show that the $\frac{d}{dx}[\csc^{[-1]}{x} = \frac{-1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$.

---

$$
\begin{align*}
   y &= \csc^{[-1]}{x}
\\ \csc{y} &= x
\\ \frac{1}{\sin{y}} &= x
\\ \frac{1}{x} &= \sin{y}
\end{align*}
$$

$\hskip 1.85in$ [image]

$$
\\ \begin{align*}
\\ \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{x}\right] &=  \frac{d}{dx}[\sin{y}]
\\ \frac{-1}{x^2} &= y^{\prime}(\cos{y})
\\ \frac{-1}{x^2(\cos{y})} &= y^{\prime}
\\ \frac{-1}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} &= y^{\prime}
\\
\\ \end{align*} 
$$

---

At this point, I don't see how to modify the equality in such a way that it resembles the derivative as given, lest $|x| = x$.

Comment: In your triangle $\sin y=x$ and not $\sin y=1/x$.

Comment: @mickep Right, I pulled the graphic from somewhere else and then started working from it on that false assumption. Oops.

Comment: @mickep I fixed it to be the way I had started (and intended). However, I still don't see either, a) where my error is, or b) how $x^2 = |x|$

Comment: Now you should also update your formula for $\cos y$. It is not $\sqrt{x^2-1}$.

Comment: $$
a = \cos{y} \\
b = 1 \\
c = x \\
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \\
\cos^2{y} + 1^2 = x^2 \\
\cos{y} = \sqrt{x^2-1^2} \\
$$

Why do you say it isn't $\sqrt{x^2 - 1}$?

Comment: In your image $\cos y=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$.

Comment: It is. But by the Pythagorean Theorem shouldn't side $a$ be $a = \cos{y} = \sqrt{x^2-1}$?

Comment: It depends on what sides you have in your triangle. In your case, no.